# nested if vlookup excel formula

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup, nested-if

```
=IF(DEAN=Hide_Only,IF(VLOOKUP(F5&$B$13,$Y$13:$AF$429,IF($Z$11=$B$6,2,IF($B$6=$AA$11,3,IF($B$6=$AB$11,4,IF($B$6=$AC$11,5,IF($B$6=$AD$11,6,IF($B$6=$AE$11,7,8)))))),FALSE)<D4,D4,VLOOKUP(F5&$B$13,$Y$13:$AF$429,IF($Z$11=$B$6,2,IF($B$6=$AA$11,3,IF($B$6=$AB$11,4,IF($B$6=$AC$11,5,IF($B$6=$AD$11,6,IF($B$6=$AE$11,7,8)))))),FALSE)),VLOOKUP(F5&$B$13,$Y$13:$AC$429,IF($Z$11=$B$6,2,IF($B$6=$AA$11,3,IF($B$6=$AB$11,4,IF($B$6=$AC$11,5,IF($B$6=$AD$11,6,IF($B$6=$AE$11,7,8)))))),FALSE))
```

So Far I have this excel formula, but it gives me #REFI error. This formula worked before I added AD,AE,AF columns into the formula. Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: seems like you are try to match `B6` to a range of cells. it would be better if you could post screenshot of your data and what you are trying to achieve. correcting a formula without knowing what is required would be difficult.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could explain a little more on what you need, sample data and a screen shot of your excel. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the definitions of the named ranges `DEAN` and `Hide_Only`. The `#Ref` error indicates a wrong reference and these are the only two references that are not spelled out in the formula.

A named range will return a #Ref error if the rows/columns it refers to are removed.